# How to remove an element with jquery from a variable containing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a forum were users can quote other people's comments.
When you click quote on a comment, it gets the html of that comment and puts it into a little box which says `Quote: Original post by a member`, like most forums do.

However, when I reply to a comment containing a quote, it returns

```
Quote: Original post by a member
      Quote: Original post by a member
```

So when I post the next reply, it has two quotes piled on top of each other.
What I would like to do is remove the quote from the original comment so that only 1 quote is ever shown. The ID of the quote is `span.threadreply` and i can remove it from the DOM using the below code.

```
$("#somereplyid span.threadreply").remove()
```

But this removes it from the page, which I don't want to do.
I have the HTML of `somereplyid` in a variable labeled `reply`. How using jQuery can i sanitize this variable to remove span.threadreply without removing it from the actual document?

If I was unclear in anyway please tell me so I can edit and improve the question.

Comment: Why does this have php tag?

Comment: it was one of the suggested tags @RonniSkansing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this to define your reply variable:

```
var reply = $('#reply').clone().find('span.threadreply').remove().end().html();
```

Comment: I dont want to remove `span.threadreply` from the page, I want to remove it from the variable `somereplyid` which contains the HTML of `$('#reply')`

Comment: @ben, exactly. That is what my suggestion is for. If your variable `reply`is a string with html this should work.

Comment: `reply = $('#reply').html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
$(reply).find('span.threadreply').remove();` Is my code, but it returns the error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: some html of a simply reply`